# UITabBarItem appearance is throwing a EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, 64-bit

I have this chunk of code to change the tab bar kerning

```
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:2.0f, NSKernAttributeName, nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

in the app delegate, it's throwing an EXC_BAD_ACCESS when I enabled **64 bit** support for my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot store primitive values (int, float etc.) in an `NSDictionary` (or other collection types).

Try wrapping it into an `NSNumber` (which is done by the short-hand syntax `@( )`):

```
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@(2.0f), NSKernAttributeName, nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

And, by the way, you should really use the modern dictionary syntax, which is much more readable:

```
NSDictionary *attributes = @{
    NSKernAttributeName: @(2.0f)
};
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:attributes];
```

Comment: Thanks! do you know why this specific case is only happens when I added the 64bit support?

Comment: Hm, I can only guess that it has to do with the fact that floats are 32-bit on iOS, thus they match the size of a pointer (which is what you should pass here) on 32-bit architectures, but not on 64-bit. But still, it seems extremely unlikely that you will hit a valid memory address "by accident".. Anyways, I'm pretty sure that the resulting text kerning wasn't correct even if it didn't crash on 32-bit, right?

Comment: It did not change anything for me. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarItem_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBarItem/setTitleTextAttributes:forState:

checked on above link only for keys can be customized,
NSString *const UITextAttributeFont;
NSString *const UITextAttributeTextColor;
NSString *const UITextAttributeTextShadowColor;
NSString *const UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset;

Comment: @MPG What did not change what? This question was about a crash due to accessing an invalid memory address, not the actual text attributes.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion created. Setting NSNumber in NSKernAttributeName works well when used in UILabel but not in UITabBarItem. So I meant, setting NSKernAttributeName in titleTextAttributes did not change kerning or character spacing for UITabBarItem.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the docs say that only a few options may be customized - I don't have further experience with that, sorry. As I said, I didn't really look into the actual appearance/text attributes stuff here, since the question was about boxing primitives and dictionary syntax.